# Getting debug symbol's module name

Tags: c++, module, symbols, dbghelp

Is there a way to get the module's name of a debug symbol obtained by using dbgHelp in C++/Windows?
thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SymGetModuleBase` to get the module base address for a symbol - then `GetModuleFileName` to find the associated DLL/EXE.

Comment: I understand that I can use the module base address as the "HMODULE" that GetModuleFileName requests? :)

Comment: @Idov: Yep - HMODULE really is the base address a DLL is loaded at.